# Virtuemart order confirmation

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am using Virtuemart 2.x in Joomla 2.5. I have used a payments gateway plugin which does not allow automatic confirmation after payment has been done.

I have used a custom script for Relay Response. My script is called after the payment is completed. Now I have invoke to default virtuemart functions for order confirmation.

I do not want to update the order status directly with the database via query as it is not the proper approach and it is restricting other plugins(subscription) which is invoked in the default confirmation process.

Please advise.

Comment: For me it's a bit unclear what you're asking. Do you get a confirmation from the payment gateway (return url)?

Comment: Yes, I get a return URL. But that URL does not belongs to Virtuemart page.